# How to get camera angle for Canon camera?

Tags: lua, camera, chdk

Is it possible to get camera`s pitch angle from CHDK script written on Lua?

[image]

[Here](https://app.assembla.com/spaces/chdkde/subversion/source/HEAD/scripts/horizon/horizon.lua) I found code, which indicate camera angle in screen plane. It uses information from lens stabilizer sensor. But I can`t understand, how to get angle betwen optical axis and ground plane?

*P.S. Universal solution not mandatory, enouth to make it work on SX220 model.*

Comment: @Piglet, Yes, this script works on my camera.

Comment: Check which of the axis values changes when you tilt the camera.

Comment: `GetISLensEViCaxis` always return -1. `A` value changes when i move up/down optical axis. I have taked video to demonstrate: https://yadi.sk/i/5HnCcMXHwx2PUQ

Comment: yeah forget about C, that doesn't make too much sense for a DSLR so I guess they only output 2 axis. so use the readings of axis A to get your angle. what is your problem then?